# How do I change the comment color in emacs lua-mode.el?

Tags: emacs, lua

The title is pretty self explanatory.

I would like to change the comment colour from black to green in lua-mode.

I've tried putting this into .emacs
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-string-face "red")

But it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the cursor in the comment, and type <kbd>M-x customize-face RET</kbd>, it will offer to customize the correct face automatically (in this case `font-lock-comment-face` as Rupert mentioned).  This gives you a nice way to play around with different changes to the face (to get exactly the right color etc.) and then save it to your `.emacs`.  This is the easiest way to find out any face that you want to change.

Comment: That's true for block comments, i.e. --[[, but for single line comments the typeface is showing as "default".

Comment: I should point out that I've tried both the stable and current beta snapshots from http://immerrr.github.com/lua-mode/

Comment: I'm using emacs 23.3.1 in 64bit Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I'm awarding you the answer.  Although the lua-mode I had tried in emacs 23 wasn't detecting single line comments.  Upgrading to emacs 24 and installing lua-mode with the package-manager and it then worked.  I can then customize the color how I wish.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my version of Emacs, if I call `describe-face` on a bit of a comment in a Lua file, I get `font-lock-comment-face`, rather than `font-lock-string-face`. Have you changed the wrong variable?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

Uninstalled emacs 23
apt-get remove emacs

Followed the instructions from: https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs
Installed emacs-starter-kit: https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit

Installed lua-mode with M-x package-install RET lua-mode

Restarted, and loaded a lua file.  Now both single and multi-line comments have the same comment color and I can change it by setting font-lock-comment-face color which by default is brickred, to darkgreen according to Ivan's answer above.